# How do I access child div of class = results that doesn't have any class or id attached with it

Tags: html, css

I want to change the style of div class which has only text. In this case, I want to modify the text "Afrikaans: Books by Language" using the parent class = "results" with the child property of CSS.

```
<div class = "results">
...
...
    <div>
        Afrikaans : Books by Language
    </div>
...
...
</div>
```

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: `.class > div` *"The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the direct children of elements matched by the first."*  Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, is look for the direct child of your class and their element.

> *"The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It
>   matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are
>   the direct children of elements matched by the first."*

Doc/Ref [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

Example:

```
.results > div {
    //CSS goes here
}
```